# Divisor function problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question asking for patterns in numbers of factors.

We had to say how many factors are in 234 (12), 768 has 2^8*3

I should probably write that I get the pattern now and it holds true for all numbers.

If I write a number in its prime factors

234 = 3^2*2^1*13^1

Basically 3 can appear 2 times, but there is the possibility of factoring without using the number 3, so that means there are 2+1 times, similarly for 2 has 1+1 times and 13 has 1+1 times

therefore (2+1)(1+1)(1+1) = 12 total factors and it works for all numbers?

9 = 3^2 = 2+1 factors...

Am I on the right track now? Thanks all!

Comment: Hint: $234 = 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 13$, $348 = 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 29$, $510 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 17$. It's the structure of the prime factorisation that determines the number of divisors.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you write out $$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$$

How can you produce divisors of $n$? Well, first pick an integer $0\leq \ell_1\leq\alpha_1$, then pick one $0\leq \ell_2\leq\alpha_2$, $\ldots$, and finally $0\leq \ell_n\leq\alpha_n$. I then claim $$m=p_n^{\ell_1}\cdots p_n^{\ell_n}$$ divides $n$, and any divisor is of this form.

It follows I can choose $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdots(\alpha_n+1)$ divisors of $n$, since I can choose $\alpha_i+1$ integers with $0\leq \ell\leq \alpha_i$ in each step.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [number-of-divisors function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), and can be easily computed given the prime factorization of a given number, by counting how many ways there are to combine the powers of those primes dividing a given number